# python gi.repository Notify and new line "\n"

Tags: python, notifications, configparser, libnotify

I'm not able to display a new line in 'gi.repository Notification'. It works when i use string constant within a program, but fails when i read string from configuration file using ConfigParser class.

**test.ini**

```
[NOTIFICATIONS]
test1 = Hello,\n{username}!
```

**test.py:**

```
import ConfigParser
from gi.repository import Notify

# notifyText = "Hello, {username}" - will work
data = {'username': 'sudo', 'test': 'test'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()                              
    cfg.read('test.ini')
    notifyText = cfg.get('NOTIFICATIONS', 'test1').format(**data)

    Notify.init('Test')
    notification = Notify.Notification('Test', notifyText)
    notification.show()
```

The output of current program will be: 'Hello\nsudo!' However, if i hardcode this string (commented line) in my program then it's displayed as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` isn't treated specially when a config file is read by a `ConfigParser`, it's interpreted as a litreral `\n`.

If you want a newline, just continue the option string on the next line:

```
[NOTIFICATIONS]
test1 = Hello,
        {username}!
```

Each line starting with whitespace is treated as continuation of the previous line, the whitespace will be removed, but the newline stays:

```
>>> print(cfg.get('NOTIFICATIONS', 'test1'))
Hello,
{username}!
>>>
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's so straightforward and easy. Thank you very much.